# Exclude Globs not working in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, youtube

So I am writing my own chrome extension and I have the following content_scripts:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*.youtube.com/*"],
    "exclude_globs": ["*user*"],
    "css": ["youtube.css"]
}]
```

As you can see, it runs on youtube. It should however not run on youtube.com/user/, which is why I have an exclude_globs field. However, its not working and it still runs when viewing a user's channel. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known [bug in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100106) , as a work around use [insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-insertCSS)

**Ex:**

Following Code in `background.js` will do the same job as in `manifest.json`

```
//Use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(integer tabId, object changeInfo, Tab tab) {...}); as applicable to ensure it works on every page     
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {
            code: "document.body.bgColor='red'",
            "all_frames": true
        });
    });
```

OR

```
//Use chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(integer tabId, object changeInfo, Tab tab) {...}); as applicable to ensure it works on every page
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {
        file: {file:"content.css"},
        "all_frames": true
    });
});
```

Ensure you have enough permissions in manifest

```
/* in manifest.json */
"permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*"
],
```

**References**

a) [insertCSS](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-insertCSS)

b) [Programmatic Injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't this require me to click a button to apply the CSS? I would rather it loaded automatically. I also experimented with using JS instead of CSS, and then it does indeed follow excludes correctly... however, there is a delay on when the CSS is loaded and then you can actively watch as the CSS is loaded up and the page shifts around... something I don't want.

Comment: @JasonAxelrod:This is a sample, you can eliminate chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {}) code , and add tabs listener this runs when page is loaded every time; If you want it to run through manifest file rather some coding, eliminate "exclude_globs" field and give all possible url's in matches, it is work around for bug in manifest for css;Updated my answer as well